# Which song plays when Alucard walks in the forest in episode 1 of Hellsing original?

Tags: music, hellsing

There is a music that plays in Episode 1 at the 07:14 mark, just as Alucard walks in the forest. Could anyone identify that song and the OST?

Answer (score 1):

It's called [Kannouteki Yuuwaku No Wana Ni Hamatta Hidariashi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ezL1fGxjibI) *(trans.: Left Foot Trapped In A Sensual Seduction)* by [Yasushi Ishii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yasushi_Ishii), also called as [Alucard's Theme](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhSbxmAfoTA).

It's the 6th song on the [first OST CD](https://www.discogs.com/Yasushi-Ishii-Raid-Hellsing-Original-Soundtrack/release/2586914) titled Raid.